# How to use login credentials from yaml in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new in ruby and I can't move forward from using login cred. from a yml file for a ruby project .I have a basic yml file

```
login:
  urls:
    gmail: "https://accounts.google.com/signin"
  users:
        username: something
        password: something_new
```

I've created a yml.rb with require yml ,and access the yml path & loading the file .
But I don't know how to go through users/username ... in my test.rb :( .I've added in the "it " a variable to store the yml class and at the end i'm trying with

```
expect data['valid_user']

expect data['login']['urls']['gmail']
expect data['login']['users']['username']
```

but in the terminal I receive th error "NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass "

**Update**
Here is my `yml.rb`

```
require 'rspec'
require 'yaml'

class YamlHelper
  @env = {}
  def initialize
    file = "#{Dir.pwd}path of yml file"
    @env = YAML.load_file(file)
  end

  def get_variables
    @env
  end
end
```

Here is my `test.rb` file

```
describe 'My behaviour' do
  before(:each) do
    @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox 
  end
  it 'verifies yml login' do
    yaml_helper = YamlHelper.new
    data = yaml_helper.get_variables
    expect data['valid_user']
    expect test_data['login']['urls']['gmail']
    expect test_data['login']['users']['username']
    expect test_data['login']['users']['password']
  end
  after(:each) do @browser.quit   
 end
```

Can anyone take a look ?
thanks in advance

Have a lovely day

Comment: Take a look at what?  Can you show the yml.rb file?

Comment: Hi SteveTurczyn ,

Comment: How do you define `data`? Post your full `test.rb` file.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you share a bit more information about that error in the terminal? Does it have a line number or filename near it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code is *almost* there. When I'm debugging this sort of thing I'll often try to distil it down to the most basic test first

Something like:

```
require 'yaml'
file = "#{Dir.pwd}/data.yml"
data = YAML.load_file(file)

data['valid_user']
#=> nil

data['login']['urls']['gmail']
#=> "https://accounts.google.com/signin"

data['login']['users']['username']
#=> "something"
```

From the above you can see there's probably a typo in your `test.rb` file: `test_data` should most likely be `data`. Also, your YAML file doesn't contain the `valid_user` key, so you probably want to remove it from the test, at least for now.

The other two keys load fine.

The error you're seeing `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` means that one of the hashes you're variables you're *treating* like a hash is actually `nil`. This sort of bug is fairly common when you're diving into nested hashes. It means one of two things:

1. You've correctly descended into the hash, but the data is not present in the YAML.
2. The data is present in the YAML, but you're not getting to it correctly.

One change you can make that will make this code a bit more resilient is to replace:

```
test_data['login']['users']['username']
```

with:

```
test_data.dig('login', 'users', 'username')
```

The latter uses [dig](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig), which delves into the data structure and tries to return the value you're after, but if it gets a `nil` back at any point it'll just return `nil`, rather than throwing an exception.

Finally, for the test you've pasted here, you don't need the `before(:each)` or `after(:each)` blocks – Selenium is only necessary for browser testing.

Comment: Many thanks @spikeheap . It works with test_data.dig('login','users', 'username')

Comment: Great, if this helps please mark this answer with the tick :)